# C# - Cast child class to parent with variable type

Tags: c#, casting

I'm experiencing an unexpected issue.

I would like to cast a child class with a special type to his parent class with a generic type but the compiler do not want this to happen...

Here is my parent class:

```
public abstract class DataSource<T>
{
    // Abstract methods and constructor
}
```

One of the child classes:

```
public class XlsxDataSource : DataSource<Row>
{
    // Overriden methods and constructor
}
```

And the code giving the error:

```
XlsxDataSource dataSource = new XlsxDataSource();

var dataSources = new Dictionary<long, DataSource<Object>>();

dataSources[dataSource.id] = (DataSource<Object>) dataSource;
```

As you can see, I have a `Dictionary` that can contain many `DataSources` regardless of the child type.

But the last line is giving the next compile error:

```
Cannot convert type 'EDS.Models.XlsxDataSource' to 'EDS.Models.DataSource<object>'
```

And I don't get why, as `XlsxDataSource` is a child from `DataSource` and the type in `XlsxDataSource` is explicitly `Row` wich is obviously implementing `System.Object`.

> Edit

The co-variant interface is not working in my case.

Here is my modified code:

```
public interface IDataSource<T, in T1>
{
    List<T> GetAllRows();

    List<Object> GetValues(T1 row); 
}
```

The abstract class:

```
public abstract class DataSource<T, T1> : IDataSource<T, T1>
{
    public abstract List<T> GetAllRows();

    public abstract List<Object> GetValues(T1 row); 
}
```

And finally the less derived class:

```
public class XlsxDataSource : DataSource<Row, Row>, IDataSource<Row, Row>
{
    public abstract List<Row> GetAllRows();

    public abstract List<Object> GetValues(Row row); 
}
```

Here is the casting:

```
IDataSource<Object, Object> datasource = (IDataSource<Object, Object>) new XlsxDataSource();
```

But casting an `XlsxDataSource` to an `IDataSource` object is resulting in an `InvalidCastException`:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'EDS.Models.XlsxDataSource' to type 'EDS.Models.IDataSource`2[System.Object,System.Object]'.
```

Comment: That's because it isn't a `DataSource<Object>`, it's a `DataSource<Row>`.  If you want co-variance you'll have to work with interfaces instead of classes.

Comment: But I have a generic constructor in my `DataSource` class so there is no redundant code, wich is impossible with an interface.

Comment: You can still have an abstract class between the interface and the child classes.  It's just that co-variance only works if you use an interface reference. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx

Comment: why do you need to cast at all?

Comment: Because otherwise I can not add an `XlsxDataSource` object to a `Dictionary` that only accept `DataSource<Object>` objects...
When I try, here is the error that I get: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'EDS.Models.XlsxDataSource' to 'EDS.Models.DataSource<object>'`

Comment: @Renlidacha What you might actually need then is a non-generic interface type, though that would limit what the interface would allow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a co-variant interface for this to work

```
public interface IDataSource<out T> {}

public abstract class DataSource<T> : IDataSource<T> {}

public class XlsxDataSource : DataSource<Row> {}
```

Will allow the following

```
XlsxDataSource dataSource = new XlsxDataSource();
var dataSources = new Dictionary<long, IDataSource<Object>>();
dataSources[dataSource.id] = (IDataSource<Object>) dataSource;
```

But note that you should only use co-variance if the type `T` is only used as the return types of methods or for read only properties (that is it only comes out of the interface and is never inserted in).

**EDIT**

Based on your edit you now have two generic types `T` and `T1`.  You have defined `T1` as contra-variant with `in` which is correct for how you use that type, however contra-variance only allows you to assign to a more derived type and not to a less derived type.  Further you didn't set `T` to be variant at all though it could be co-variant if you change the return type to `IEnumerable<T>`.  Here's what you can do.

```
public interface IDataSource<out T, in T1>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAllRows();

    List<Object> GetValues(T1 row); 
}

public abstract class DataSource<T, T1> : IDataSource<T, T1>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetAllRows();

    public abstract List<Object> GetValues(T1 row); 
}

public class XlsxDataSource : DataSource<Row, Row>, IDataSource<Row, Row>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<Row> GetAllRows();

    public abstract List<Object> GetValues(Row row); 
}

public class DerivedRow : Row {}
```

That would allow you to do something like

```
XlsxDataSource dataSource = new XlsxDataSource();
IDataSource<object, DerivedRow> interfaceReference = dataSource;
```

You can assign it to allow for more derived types of `T1` because you are passing them into the interface.  So the method `GetValues(Row row)` can take a `DerivedRow`, but it cannot take a `object`.  Then for `T1` you can assign to less derived types becuase you are getting those values out of the interface.  So the method `GetAllRows` returns an `IEnumerable<Row>` which is assignable to `IEnumerable<object>` because `IEnumerable` is covariant and `object` is less derived than `Row`.

Now what you could do is create a non-generic interface to handle this.

```
public interface IDataSource
{
    List<object> GetAllRows();

    List<object> GetValues(object row);
}

public abstract class DataSource<T> : IDataSource
{
    public abstract List<T> GetAllRows();

    List<object> IDataSource.GetValues(object row)
    {
        return GetValues((T)row);
    }

    public abstract List<object> GetValues(T row);

    List<object> IDataSource.GetAllRows()
    {
        return GetAllRows().Cast<object>().ToList();
    }
}

public class XlsxDataSource : DataSource<Row>
{
    public override List<object> GetValues(Row row)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override List<Row> GetAllRows()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to do

```
XlsxDataSource dataSource = new XlsxDataSource();
var dataSources = new Dictionary<long, IDataSource>();
dataSources[5] = dataSource;
```

But now you've lost strong typing, which means you don't know the actual type of the objects in the lists that are returned by the interfaces methods and worse you could pass in an object to `GetValues` that will result in a casting exception.  So ultimately a better question is why does the dictionary need to down grade the generic type on something that is clearly not co-variant.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, I was looking on how to implement co-variant interfaces :)

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work, could you check my edit please?

Comment: @Renlidacha I've updated my answer based on your edit.  But basically what you tried didn't work because it was not co-variant on both generic types.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The point is that I have to manage several types of `DataSource` such as Excel files, Acces files, etc. . As the methods names are the same for each datasource but not the implementation, I need to be able to cast specific datasources such as `XslxDataSource` to a generic datasource as I don't know what will be the type of the datasource at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

That's error occurs because generic classes in C# aren't covariant.

Covariance enables you to use a more derived type than originally specified.

In C# covariance is possible in interfaces, so if you can convert `DataSource<T>` class to an interface a possible solution is:

```
public interface IDataSource<out T>
{
    ...
}

public abstract class DataSource<T> : IDataSource<T>
{
    ...
}

public class XlsxDataSource : DataSource<Row>
{
    // Overriden methods and constructor
}
```

And works with the dictionary like this:

```
XlsxDataSource dataSource = new XlsxDataSource();
var dataSources = new Dictionary<long, IDataSource<Object>>();
dataSources[dataSource.id] = (IDataSource<Object>)dataSource;
```

Comment: That's contra-variant.  You need to use `out` for co-variance.